# Expected value of the maximum of the difference between two random variables and zero

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ and independent random variables with different distributions, how do you compute:

$E[max(X - Y,0)]?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U=X-Y$. Then $\max\{U,0\}=\begin{cases}U,&U\ge0\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. This means required expectation is $\int_0^\infty uf_U(u)~du$ where you need to calculate mass/density function of $U,f_U(u)$.

Comment: Note that not all random variables have a density function.